# Extract DVD subtitles programmatically

Tags: ruby, dvd, subtitle

I'm trying to extract subtitles from unencrypted DVDs with a program, so I can save them seperately. I know there are programs that do that (I found this page for example: http://www.bunkus.org/dvdripping4linux/en/separate/subtitles.html), but I would like to be able to do it with a library call or something like that (do libdvdread or libdvdnav support this), preferably using ruby.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at Handbrake, it allows you to extract video, audio and subtitles.

There is also the Handbrake manual [here](https://trac.handbrake.fr/wiki/HandBrakeGuide), and the subtitles section [here](https://trac.handbrake.fr/wiki/Subtitles), that can provide more information.

This isn't in Ruby but you should be able to call the Handbrake CLI from Ruby without any problems.

Comment: Please, do not use short link when you want to link a ressource. Use the full url.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any library, which would be able to do this.

In ruby you can call programs. For example to get a directory listing you can do

```
files= `ls "#{dir}"`.to_a
```

The backtick variant gives you stdout of the calle program.

To know wheter a file exists

```
system("ls \"#{file}\"")
```

The `system` variant tells you whether the return value of the called program was `0`.

Using this two methods, you can do almost anything with noninteracitve programs. The programs described in http://www.bunkus.org/dvdripping4linux/en/separate/subtitles.html seme to be suitable for this kind of control.

Be carefull with escaping arguments you give to external programs. If an argumend is `"; rm -rf *; ls ".` undesirable things may happen.

Comment: Do `system("ls", file)` instead to avoid injection attacks.